# VMWare vmfs vs NFS datastore with vmdk?

Tags: vmware-vmdk, vmfs

I want to add a new harddisk to an existing VM and want the best performance possible. The new hard disk will exist on an NFS datastore. Currently I did the following:

- Created new vmdk on NFS datastore
- Created new lvm partition using fdisk
- Create new physical volume, volume group, and logical volume (2TB)
- Created ext3 partition on logical volume

Is there a better way to do this? Should I be doing some vmware-ish file system instead?

Comment: That is correct... assuming you still need the features that capturing a disk inside a VMDK provides, snapshot, etc, otherwise you could mount that same NFS datastore from the VM directly as recommended by Kyle Smith below.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fastest performance would be to cut out the middle-man and mount the NFS volume directly within the Guest VM, rather than emulating a new hard disk in software.

Comment: I think our storage might support iscsi too. Would using iscsi directly from the VM be the best solution? Would it be better to create an iscsi datastore within ESXi?

Comment: Both good questions.  Depending on your architecture, I would think iSCSI would outperform NFS.  Running some tests wouldn't be too difficult, and would be worth knowing the results of.

Comment: There's no way to know what will work best without testing with real life loads. Storage system behavior varies widely. I/O profiles vary widely. Don't believe anyone who will tell you "iscsi is faster than nfs" or vice versa.